# Why do some technologies have their own StackExchange?

Tags: discussion

Unix.  LaTeX.  Salesforce.  Magento.  The Stack Exchange API.  These are all developer-oriented technologies...yet questions about them are best asked on their dedicated Stack Exchange sites.  *What is it with these (and other) developer-oriented technologies that warrant their own Stack Exchange?*

Answer (score 2):

If someone feels like a particular subject deserves its own site, a proposal is created in [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) and if it gains enough interest and support it goes through various stage gates until graduation, if it is sufficiently self-empowered to do so.

Many proposals fail, often because they don't have sufficient support from the community. The ones you mention have proven the support and the ability to stand alone - and for some, being created outside the big-3 offers them some essential autonomy.

You'll find, if you browse the [full sites list on Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/sites), that there are a huge number of sites that have reached public beta, and many of these have graduated.

Answer (score 1):

A site warrants an own site if there is enough community to support it. Also it requires to be a subject more or less on its own. (A dedicated site for C# might get enough audience, but it is too related to other programming related stuff).

Each site has a clear purpose and shouldn't have too much overlap with another site. In that way it is possible you have a programming question related to Unix: off-topic on Unix but on-topic on Stack Overflow.